# pyPDF bad xref character at startxref

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm using pyPDF for pdf page extraction and merging. My issues isn't completely dependent on pyPDF, since I've ran into the same type of error with pdfSharp in the past on the same pdf file.

The problem is that I'm getting an error when trying to read in some pdf documents we receive from our vendors. I can't tell them to fix them, so I have to deal with it on our end. Right now I'm using iText in java to handle pdf merging and it doesn't have any issues with these files, but iText is slow and harder to maintain than pyPDF. pyPDF has a section for reading in the xref tables. In that section there are a few options, either the line starts with "xref", the line starts with a number, or the line starts with a "xref", but there was an extra character before the x.

In my case the line starts with "196 0 obj" but the next line is "<< /Length 197 0 R". pyPDF and pdfSharp don't recognize that, theyre trying to read that as a cross reference and throw up exceptions. *Any suggestions of what I can do to avoid this or to patch pyPDF? It may be bad formed, but I need to work around it just as Acrobat and iText do.*

Here is the section from pdf.py in the pyPDF library. It's a lot of code, but the important bits are the if statements in the series starting with **if x == "x":**

```
# read all cross reference tables and their trailers
    self.xref = {}
    self.xref_objStm = {}
    self.trailer = DictionaryObject()
    while 1:
        # load the xref table
        stream.seek(startxref, 0)
        x = stream.read(1)
        if x == "x":
            # standard cross-reference table
            ref = stream.read(4)
            if ref[:3] != "ref":
                raise utils.PdfReadError, "xref table read error"
            readNonWhitespace(stream)
            stream.seek(-1, 1)
            while 1:
                num = readObject(stream, self)
                readNonWhitespace(stream)
                stream.seek(-1, 1)
                size = readObject(stream, self)
                readNonWhitespace(stream)
                stream.seek(-1, 1)
                cnt = 0
                while cnt < size:
                    line = stream.read(20)
                    # It's very clear in section 3.4.3 of the PDF spec
                    # that all cross-reference table lines are a fixed
                    # 20 bytes.  However... some malformed PDF files
                    # use a single character EOL without a preceeding
                    # space.  Detect that case, and seek the stream
                    # back one character.  (0-9 means we've bled into
                    # the next xref entry, t means we've bled into the
                    # text "trailer"):
                    if line[-1] in "0123456789t":
                        stream.seek(-1, 1)
                    offset, generation = line[:16].split(" ")
                    offset, generation = int(offset), int(generation)
                    if not self.xref.has_key(generation):
                        self.xref[generation] = {}
                    if self.xref[generation].has_key(num):
                        # It really seems like we should allow the last
                        # xref table in the file to override previous
                        # ones. Since we read the file backwards, assume
                        # any existing key is already set correctly.
                        pass
                    else:
                        self.xref[generation][num] = offset
                    cnt += 1
                    num += 1
                readNonWhitespace(stream)
                stream.seek(-1, 1)
                trailertag = stream.read(7)
                if trailertag != "trailer":
                    # more xrefs!
                    stream.seek(-7, 1)
                else:
                    break
            readNonWhitespace(stream)
            stream.seek(-1, 1)
            newTrailer = readObject(stream, self)
            for key, value in newTrailer.items():
                if not self.trailer.has_key(key):
                    self.trailer[key] = value
            if newTrailer.has_key("/Prev"):
                startxref = newTrailer["/Prev"]
            else:
                break
        elif x.isdigit():
            # PDF 1.5+ Cross-Reference Stream
            stream.seek(-1, 1)
            idnum, generation = self.readObjectHeader(stream)
            xrefstream = readObject(stream, self)
            assert xrefstream["/Type"] == "/XRef"
            self.cacheIndirectObject(generation, idnum, xrefstream)
            streamData = StringIO(xrefstream.getData())
            idx_pairs = xrefstream.get("/Index", [0, xrefstream.get("/Size")])
            entrySizes = xrefstream.get("/W")
            for num, size in self._pairs(idx_pairs):
                cnt = 0
                while cnt < size:
                    for i in range(len(entrySizes)):
                        d = streamData.read(entrySizes[i])
                        di = convertToInt(d, entrySizes[i])
                        if i == 0:
                            xref_type = di
                        elif i == 1:
                            if xref_type == 0:
                                next_free_object = di
                            elif xref_type == 1:
                                byte_offset = di
                            elif xref_type == 2:
                                objstr_num = di
                        elif i == 2:
                            if xref_type == 0:
                                next_generation = di
                            elif xref_type == 1:
                                generation = di
                            elif xref_type == 2:
                                obstr_idx = di
                    if xref_type == 0:
                        pass
                    elif xref_type == 1:
                        if not self.xref.has_key(generation):
                            self.xref[generation] = {}
                        if not num in self.xref[generation]:
                            self.xref[generation][num] = byte_offset
                    elif xref_type == 2:
                        if not num in self.xref_objStm:
                            self.xref_objStm[num] = [objstr_num, obstr_idx]
                    cnt += 1
                    num += 1
            trailerKeys = "/Root", "/Encrypt", "/Info", "/ID"
            for key in trailerKeys:
                if xrefstream.has_key(key) and not self.trailer.has_key(key):
                    self.trailer[NameObject(key)] = xrefstream.raw_get(key)
            if xrefstream.has_key("/Prev"):
                startxref = xrefstream["/Prev"]
            else:
                break
        else:
            # bad xref character at startxref.  Let's see if we can find
            # the xref table nearby, as we've observed this error with an
            # off-by-one before.
            stream.seek(-11, 1)
            tmp = stream.read(20)
            print tmp
            xref_loc = tmp.find("xref")
            if xref_loc != -1:
                startxref -= (10 - xref_loc)
                continue
            else:
                # no xref table found at specified location
                assert False
                break
```

Note:
My example is throwing the assert False in the last three lines

Answer (score 0):

Since 2012, pypdf changed a lot. It especially received an upgrade to be able to deal with some forms of broken xref tables.

You can fix broken PDF document with mutool from MuPDF:

```
mutool clean -d input.pdf output.pdf
```

You can then feed the fixed PDF into pypdf. Be aware that MuPDF has a commercial license (for commercial projects).